# Java8: Transform Map<String,List<String>> into Map<String,String> by joining the values

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>` that I would like to transform into a `Map<String, String>`, the values of the result would be a `String.join(" - ", values)` of the first map's values.

I know how to do it like this:

```
public Map<String,String> flatten( Map<String, List<String>> attributes) {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      attributes.forEach((k,v) -> map.put( k, String.join(" - ", v)));
      return map;
}
```

But I would like to get rid of the `new HashMap<>()` and directly do the transformation on the input.
I suspect a `collect(Collectors.groupingBy( something ) )` but I can't figure out how.
What I want looks like this:

```
public Map<String,String> flatten( Map<String, List<String>> attributes) {
    return attributes.entrySet().stream().<something>;
}
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to group by. Just collect the entries into a new `Map` :

```
Map<String, String> map = 
    attributes.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        e-> String.join(" - ", e.getValue())));
```